# string concatenation using ternary expression

Tags: php, string, ternary-operator

```
var_dump('title: ' . true? 'value1': 'value2');
```

OUTPUT:

```
value1
```

Isn't that weird? the output I was expecting is `title: value1`. What's going on?

Comment: Try `var_dump('title: ' . (true? 'value1': 'value2'));`

Comment: "Isn't that weird?" [No...](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dot operator [has a bigger precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than ternary operator. You need to put your ternary operator between parentheses such as `var_dump('title: ' . (true ? 'value1': 'value2'));`.

Comment: To clarify on this: What it's basically doing is concatenating 'title: ' and true, and then evaluating that for truthiness.

Comment: Thx for the link. Personaly I rarely use dot to concat strings but I was curious to understand. I prefer using sprintf to avoid all theses concat unexpected phpp behaviours :)